# When using AOT, changes to objects passed to forRoot are discarded when injected

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

### Overview

I am seeing odd behavior in that the properties that are added to an object through a destructuring assignment (or `Object.assign`) are present when passed to `forRoot` but are not present when injected into a service. Additionally, updates made after initialization are present when passed to `forRoot` but are not present when injected into a service. This only occurs when building with AOT.

I created a minimal project that reproduces the issue:
https://github.com/bygrace1986/wat

### Package Versions

- angular: 5.2.0
- angular-cli: 1.6.4 (my app), 1.7.4 (my test)
- typescript: 2.4.2

### Setup

Create a module that has a static `forRoot` method that will accept an object that it will then provide via an `InjectionToken` and injected into a service.

**TestModule**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { TestDependency, TEST_DEPENDENCY, TestService } from './test.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class TestModule {
  static forRoot(dependency?: TestDependency): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TestModule,
      providers: [
        TestService,
        { provide: TEST_DEPENDENCY, useValue: dependency }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**TestService**

```
import { Injectable, InjectionToken, Inject } from '@angular/core';

export interface TestDependency {
    property: string;
}

export const TEST_DEPENDENCY = new InjectionToken<TestDependency>('TEST_DEPENDENCY');

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    constructor(@Inject(TEST_DEPENDENCY) dependency: TestDependency) {
        console.log('[TestService]', dependency);
    }
}
```

### Non-mutated Object Scenario

This scenario illustrates that passing an non-mutated object to `forRoot` is properly injected into a service that depends on it.

To setup reference the `TestService` in the `app.component.html` (or somewhere where it will be injected). Pass the dependency to the `forRoot` method on the `TestModule`.

**AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestModule } from './test/test.module';
import { TestDependency } from './test/test.service';

const dependency = {
  property: 'value'
} as TestDependency;
console.log('[AppModule]', dependency)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TestModule.forRoot(dependency)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Run `ng serve --aot`.

**Output**

```
[AppModule] {property: "value"}
[TestService] {property: "value"}
```

### Mutated Object Scenario

This scenario illustrates that changes made to an object through object destructuring assignment during initialization or changes made after initialization are ignored when the provided object is injected into a service that depends on it.

To setup create a new object with additional properties and use object destructuring to assign the properties of the old object to the new. Then update a property on `dependency` and pass it to the `forRoot` method on the `TestModule`.

**AppModule**

```
const dependency = {
  property: 'value'
} as TestDependency;
const dependencyCopy = { id: 1, name: 'first', ...dependency };
dependencyCopy.name = 'last';
console.log('[AppModule]', dependencyCopy);
...
TestModule.forRoot(dependencyCopy)
```

Run `ng serve --aot`.

**Output**

```
[AppModule] {id: 1, name: "last", property: "value"}
[TestService] {id: 1, name: "first"}
```

**Unexpected Result**

Any property added by object destructuring assignment was removed and any update made after initialization is reverted between when the object is passed to `forRoot` and injected into `TestService`. In fact, it isn't event the same object (I debugged and checked with `===`). It is as if the original object that is created before assignment or mutation is being used... somehow.

### Mutated Object Provided at AppModule Scenario

This scenario illustrates that mutations to the object are not reverted when provided at the `AppModule` level rather than through `forRoot`.

To setup don't pass anything to `forRoot`. Instead use the injection token to provide the object in the `AppModule` providers list.

**AppModule**

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  TestModule.forRoot()
],
providers: [
  { provide: TEST_DEPENDENCY, useValue: dependencyCopy }
],
```

Run `ng serve --aot`.

**Output**

```
[AppModule] {id: 1, name: "last", property: "value"}
[TestService] {id: 1, name: "last", property: "value"}
```

### Question

Why do changes made to an object that is provided via `forRoot` get reverted when the object is injected into a dependent class?

### Updates

- Realized that updates after initialization are also reverted.
- Realized that this can be reproduced with just the `--aot` flag rather than the broader `--prod` flag.
- Updated to latest stable cli version (1.7.4) and still have the issue.
- Opened a bug on the `angular-cli` project: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10610
- From reading the generated code I think that the issue is in Phase 2 metadata rewriting. When only referencing the variable in `forRoot` I get this: `i0.ɵmpd(256, i6.TEST_DEPENDENCY, { id: 1, name: "first" }, [])]);`. When it is referenced in the `AppModule` provider list I get this: `i0.ɵmpd(256, i6.TEST_DEPENDENCY, i1.ɵ0, [])]);` and then this in the app module `var ɵ0 = dependencyCopy; exports.ɵ0 = ɵ0;`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The core of AOT is **[Metadata collector](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/77ff72f93b86e57ba3fdc67a60a5b00c69c9a824/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/collector.ts#L46)**.

It takes `ts.SourceFile`, then recursively walks through all AST nodes of this file and transforms all nodes to JSON representation.

Collector [checks](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/77ff72f93b86e57ba3fdc67a60a5b00c69c9a824/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/collector.ts#L339-L542) the following types of AST node at the top level of file:

```
ts.SyntaxKind.ExportDeclaration
ts.SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration
ts.SyntaxKind.TypeAliasDeclaration
ts.SyntaxKind.InterfaceDeclaration
ts.SyntaxKind.FunctionDeclaration
ts.SyntaxKind.EnumDeclaration
ts.SyntaxKind.VariableStatement
```

Angular compiler also tries to calculate all metadata at runtime by using so-called **[Evaluator](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/77ff72f93b86e57ba3fdc67a60a5b00c69c9a824/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/evaluator.ts#L125)** so that it can understand a subset of javascript expressions that is listen in [docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#expression-syntax)

It should be noted that compiler supports spread operator but only in [array literals](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/77ff72f93b86e57ba3fdc67a60a5b00c69c9a824/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/evaluator.ts#L331-L339) not in [objects](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/77ff72f93b86e57ba3fdc67a60a5b00c69c9a824/packages/compiler-cli/src/metadata/evaluator.ts#L285-L313)

### Case 1

```
const dependency = {
  property: 'value'               ===========> Non-exported VariableStatement
} as TestDependency;                           with value { property: 'value' }

imports: [
  ...,
  TestModule.forRoot(dependency)  ===========> Call expression with 
                                               ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier argument 
                                               which is calculated above
]
```

So we will get metadata like:
[image]

Note that argument is simply static object value.

### Case 2

```
const dependency = {
  property: 'value'               ===========> Non-exported VariableStatement
} as TestDependency;                           with value { property: 'value' }

const dependencyCopy = { 
  id: 1,                         ============> Non-exported VariableStatement
  name: 'first',                               with value { id: 1, name: 'first' }                       
  ...dependency                                (Spread operator is not supported here)
};
dependencyCopy.name = 'last';     ===========> ExpressionStatement is skipped
                                               (see list of supported types above)

...
TestModule.forRoot(dependencyCopy) ===========> Call expression with 
                                                ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier argument 
                                                which is calculated above
```

Here's what we get now:
[image]

### Case 3

```
providers: [
  { provide: TEST_DEPENDENCY, useValue: dependencyCopy }
],
```

In version 5 angular moved to (almost) native TS compilation process using transformers and introduces so-called **[Lower Expressions transformer](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/compiler-cli/src/transformers/lower_expressions.ts)** which basically means we can now use arrow functions in decorator metadata, for example:

```
providers: [{provide: SERVER, useFactory: () => TypicalServer}]
```

will be automatically transformed by angular compiler to the following:

```
export const ɵ0 = () => new TypicalServer();
...
providers: [{provide: SERVER, useFactory: ɵ0}]
```

Now let's read [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#metadata-rewriting):

> The compiler treats object literals containing the fields **useClass**,
>   **useValue**, **useFactory**, and **data** specially. **The compiler converts the**
>   **expression initializing one of these fields into an exported variable**,
>   which replaces the expression. This process of rewriting these
>   expressions **removes all the restrictions** on what can be in them
>   because the **compiler doesn't need to know the expression's value**—it
>   just needs to be able to **generate a reference to the value**.

Now let's see how it works in our third case:
[image]

We can see that angular now uses reference to `dependencyCopy` object. And as you have already noticed it will be used as `var ɵ0 = dependencyCopy;` in generated factory.

### Possible Solution:

**test.module.ts**

```
export class TestModule {
  static forRoot(dependency?: { data: TestDependency }): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: TestModule,
      providers: [
        TestService,
        { provide: TEST_DEPENDENCY, useValue: dependency.data }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
TestModule.forRoot({ data: dependencyCopy })
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation! Particularly the clarification about special casing objects with `useClass, useValue, useFactory, and data`.